# Django form not saving - cannot identify problem with code

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

Trying to save the below form, but it's not saving.

The traceback doesn't identify any problem, and `print(form.errors)` doesnt not return any issue.

I have the exact same code working for another page. So I am not sure what I am missing here. There has to be a typo, I cannot find it.

You will notice that I have an autocomplete function in my template. I initially thought autocomplete was not returning data in all the fields, so also tried to input data manually but not luck either.

Also tried with and without `is_ajax` but same result.

**models.py:**

```
class Venue(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(verbose_name="Address",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    town = models.CharField(verbose_name="Town",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    county = models.CharField(verbose_name="County",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    post_code = models.CharField(verbose_name="Post Code",max_length=8, null=True, blank=True)
    country_1 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country1",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    country_2 = models.CharField(verbose_name="Country2",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    longitude = models.CharField(verbose_name="Longitude",max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    latitude = models.CharField(verbose_name="Latitude",max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    web = models.URLField('Website Address')
    email_address = models.EmailField('Venue Email Address')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name) if self.name else ''
```

**forms.py:**

```
class VenueForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"name"}))
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"address"}))
    town = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"town"}))
    county = forms.CharField(max_length=100, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"county"}))
    post_code = forms.CharField(max_length=8, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"post_code"}))
    country_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"country_1"}))
    country_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=True, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"country_2"}))
    longitude = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"longitude"}))
    latitude = forms.CharField(max_length=50, required=False, widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={'id':"latitude"}))
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=120,required=False)
    web = forms.URLField(max_length=120,required=False)
    email_address = forms.CharField(max_length=120, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Venue
        fields = ['name', 'address', 'town', 'county', 'post_code','country_1','country_2','longitude','latitude','web', 'phone', 'email_address']
```

**views.py:**

```
def google_api_test(request):
    submitted = False
    form = VenueForm()
    if is_ajax(request) and request.method =="POST":
        form = VenueForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,("Success!"))
            return redirect('home')
        else :
            print(form.errors)
    context = {
    'form' : form,
    'submitted' : submitted,
    'google_api_key' : settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'base_country' : settings.BASE_COUNTRY,
    }
    return render(request,"main/google_api_test.html", context)
```

**html file:**

```
<div class = "form-group">

         <input id="autocomplete" style ="width: 500px "placeholder="Enter your address">

         <form id="venueform" method="POST" action="">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|as_crispy_errors }}
            <td class="label">Name (Name)</td>
            {{form.name| as_crispy_field}}
         </br>
            <td class="label">Street Number + Street Name (Address)</td>
            {{form.address| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Town (town)</td>
            {{form.town | as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Country(country_1)</td>
            {{form.country_1| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Post Code (post_code)</td>
            {{form.post_code| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Country(country_2)</td>
            {{form.country_2| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Country(longitude)</td>
            {{form.longitude| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">Country(latitude)</td>
            {{form.latitude| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">phone(phone)</td>
            {{form.phone| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">web(web)</td>
            {{form.web| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>
            <td class="label">email_address(email_address)</td>
            {{form.email_address| as_crispy_field}}
        </br>

        <button type="submit" value="Submit" id="profile-btn">Validate</button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I'd recommend you to check whether the form even goes to the POST method of `google_api_view` or not since you mentioned `form.errors` prints nothing.

Remove the empty `action=""` from the html form, since Django always takes current page route or url, so it is unnecessary.

Also suggest not to use `is_ajax(request)` only for one time to check(I think it's depreciated).

So, try this view:

```py
def google_api_test(request):
    submitted = False
    
    form="" # for the error - local variable 'form' referenced before assignment if occurs.
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST method") # check it prints it or not.
        form = VenueForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Success!")
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            print(form.errors)

    else: # GET request
       form = VenueForm()

    context = {
    'form' : form,
    'submitted' : submitted,
    'google_api_key' : settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'base_country' : settings.BASE_COUNTRY,
    }
    return render(request,"main/google_api_test.html", context)
```

Also share Ajax and jQuery code.

Comment: Thanks, I am not too sure what fundamental change you made from Iqbal's code but this time the form got saved. (may be it was a combination of different things like `action=""`, `is_ajax`. That being said the original code is working fine on another page, so I am sure to understand what happened. Any way, big thanks to you!

Answer (score 1):

`county` is missing in your template. It's weird that your `print(form.errors)` did not show up in your terminal - it should have

Comment: Good spotting there! I removed it, but the form is sill not saving.

Comment: Any further errors seen on browser and terminal? Just to make sure you did not miss it, you can replace `print(form.errors)` with `assert(False)` and see whether it runs

Comment: And by 'I removed it', did you mean you removed it from both model and form (which you have to since this field is required)? It might be easier to add it to the template to verify whether it work :)

Comment: No nothing is flagged. The only thing the console return is `[28/Aug/2022 16:40:45] "POST /google_api_test HTTP/1.1" 200 7992`. Which is what return with `print(form.errors)`. (thanks for sticking around!)

Comment: With regards to county - Yes, I initially added to the template after you flagged it. Quite surprisingly it was a required field, so it was weird it didnt get flag by `print(form.errors)`. But I also realised I didn't need it in the code, so I removed it from models, form and template.

Answer (score 1):

```
def google_api_test(request):
    submitted = False
    
    if is_ajax(request) and request.method == 'POST':
        print(request.POST) # Check--Are you getting form data
        form = VenueForm(data = request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,("Success!"))
            return redirect('home')
        else :
            print(form.errors)

    else:
       form = VenueForm() #Changes in here.

    context = {
    'form' : form,
    'submitted' : submitted,
    'google_api_key' : settings.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
    'base_country' : settings.BASE_COUNTRY,
    }
    return render(request,"main/google_api_test.html", context)
```

Comment: This did not work. For some reason, the addition made by Sunderam did.